# C++ : generate all subsets from set with one condition

Tags: c++

I’m trying to write code that generate all subsets from set with one condition like
If I have threshold =2, and three set:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1,3,5
1,3,4
```

**Then the program will output:**

**The generating set at the first iteration:**

```
1 = number of frequency = 3
2 = number of frequency = 1
3 = number of frequency = 3
4 = number of frequency = 2
5= number of frequency = 2
```

Since the frequency of number 2 < threshold, I will exclude this set form any further superset,

**The generating set at the second iteration**:

```
1,3 = number of frequency = 3
1,4 = number of frequency = 2
1,5 = number of frequency = 2
3,4 = number of frequency = 2
3,5= number of frequency = 2
4,5= number of frequency = 1
```

Since the frequency of number (4,5) < threshold, I will exclude this set form any further superset,

**The generating set at the third iteration**

```
1,3,4= number of frequency = 2
1,3,5= number of frequency = 2
```

**The generating set at the fourth iteration**

No more superset because (4,5) < threshold we can’t generate (1,3,4,5)

I wrote the program, and I already generate all the subset, but Failed in two things:

- I couldn't search in the map  `std::map <int,std::pair<list<int>,
  int>> CandList`  to count the similar set (number of frequency)
- I couldn't figure out how to apply the condition

Please I appreciate any help.

This my code:

```
int threshold = 2;
std::vector<std::list<int>> data;
std::map<int, int> FISupp;
typedef std::pair<list<int>, int> combo;
std::map <int,combo> CandList;
std::list<int> FrqList;



/*
input:Threshold =2, and data=
1 2 3 4 5
1 3 4 5
1 2 3 5
1 3

at first scan after PassOne function:
FISupp(1,4)
FISupp(2,2)
FISupp(3,4)
FISupp(4,4)
FISupp(5,3)

at k scan after Passk function:
---
*/
int Lsize = 2; // Level size

void ScanData()
{
    ifstream in;
    in.open("mydata.txt");
    /* mydata.txt
    1 2 3 4 5
    1 3 4 5
    1 2 3 5
    1 3
    */
    std::string line;
    int i = 0;

    while (std::getline(in, line))
    {
        std::stringstream Sline1(line);
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        std::list<int> inner;
        int info;

        while (ss >> info)
            inner.push_back(info);

        data.push_back(inner);
    }
}


/* first pass to generate first Candidates items */
void PassOne()
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::list<int>::iterator li;

        for (li = data[i].begin(); li != data[i].end(); ++li)
            FISupp[*li] += 1;
    }


    /*update the FFISupp by erasing all first Candidates items  with support < Threshold*/

    std::map<int, int> ::iterator current = FISupp.begin();

    std::list<int> ls; /* save Candidates itemes with support < Threshold*/
    while (current != FISupp.end())
    {
        if (current->second < threshold)
        {
            ls.push_back(current->first);
            current = FISupp.erase(current);
        }
        else
            ++current;
    }


    /*update the the orginal data by erasing all first Candidates items  with support < Threshold*/
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::list<int>::iterator li;
        std::list<int>::iterator item = ls.begin();

        while (item != ls.end())
        {
            for (li = data[i].begin(); li != data[i].end(); ++li)
            {
                if (*li == *item)
                {
                    li = data[i].erase(li);
                    break;
                }
            }
            ++item;
        }

    }


}


void FrequentItem(list<int> l,   int indx)
{
    int a = 0;
    for (list<int>::iterator it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it)
    {
        //std::list <int> &m2 = CandList[indx].first;

        //auto itr = m2.find(*it);

        //auto itr = std::find(CandList.begin(), CandList.end(), *it);

        auto itr = CandList.find(*it);
        if (itr != CandList.end())
        {
            a += CandList[indx].second;
            CandList[indx].first.push_back(*it);
            CandList[indx].second = a;
        }

    }

}

int ind = 0;
void Passk(int j, std::list<int>::iterator Itm , int q = 0)
{

    if (Lsize == q)
    {
        FrequentItem(FrqList, ind);
        ++ind;
        return;
    }

    else
    {

        for (std::list<int>::iterator Itm2 = Itm; Itm2 != data[j].end(); ++Itm2)
        {
                FrqList.push_back(*Itm2);
                Passk(j,  ++Itm2, q + 1);
                FrqList.pop_back();
                --Itm2;

        }

    }


}



void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int temp = 0;
    int j = -1;

    ScanData();
    PassOne();

    while (Lsize <= data.size()) // How to stop the loop when there is no more candidate >= threshold???
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::list<int>::iterator items = data[i].begin();
            Passk(++j, items);  
        }

        j = -1;
        ++ Lsize;

    }

    data.clear();
    system("PAUSE");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Neither the objective nor the logic of your program is clear to me.

Comment: checking I understand your stipulation: you want to list all sets `S` such that `S` is a subset of at least `threshold` number of sets in your list; and you want to sort the output by size?

Comment: consider using `std::set` instead of `std::list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'll try for an answer. But first the assumptions:

- You are working with *ordered* sets, i.e. the elements are strictly ascending.
- You consider "normal" sets, i.e. no multi-sets where duplicate elements might appear.
- Both assumptions might easily be relaxed, but I'll use this as base.

For this scenario, it might be more natural to encode your sets by bit-vectors (for instance using `std::vector<bool>` or `boost::dynamic_bitset<>`). In such a bit-vector, if the `i`-th element is set, it means that the number `i` is present in the set.

For example, your three sets are represented by this

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 0
```

---

**Iteration 1**: In your first iteration, you simply have to sum the elements, which is rather easy in this representation. One obtains

```
    1 1 1 1 1
    1 0 1 0 1
    1 0 1 1 0
   -----------
    3 1 3 2 2
```

Next you discard all elements below your threshold, which simply amounts to setting the second row to zero:

```
    1 0 1 1 1
    1 0 1 0 1
    1 0 1 1 0
```

---

**Iteration K**: Here, you count the occurence of all K-subsets, and discard them if their number is smaller than threshold. That is, formally, you generate the K-stencils

```
{ 1 1 0 0 0, 1 0 1 0 0, ... , 0 0 0 1 1}   (for K=2)
{ 1 1 1 0 0, 1 1 0 1 0, ... , 0 0 1 1 1}   (for K=3)
```

and so on. For each of these `K`-stencils, you count the occurence and eventually discard (note that `K` may also be one). So, you have three tasks, namely

1. Generation: is obtained by permutation of the initial bitvector `{1 ... 1 0 ... 0}`, where `K` elements are ordered to the left.
2. Counting: loop over the vectors of your set, and use bitwise `and` to check whether the current vector contains the stencil. For example: `1 0 1 1 1 & 0 0 0 1 1 == 0 0 0 1 1`?.
3. Discarding: apply the inversed stencil via bitwise `and` (inversion is done via `flip()`). This will remove the relevant subsets. Finally discard any subset smaller than the number of iterations (e.g., in iteration 3, subset of size 2 are removed).

Here is an implemetation using primarily `boost::dynamic_bitset<>`, but `std::vector<bool>` for the permutations (that is because I didn't want to code a permutation by myself, but this can certainly be improved). Note that there are no maps or other more sophisticated storage schemes:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

//only for nice output of a bitset
std::string screenOutput(const boost::dynamic_bitset<>& bits)
{
    int n=bits.size();
    std::string ret;
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;--i)
    {
        if(bits[i])
        {
           std::stringstream out;
           out<<i+1<<" ";
           ret=out.str()+ret;
        }
    }
    return "{"+ret+"}";
}

//function implementing the actual logic
void removeSubsets(std::vector<boost::dynamic_bitset<> > &currentSet, size_t K, size_t thresh)
{
    size_t n=currentSet.front().size();

    //create initial stencil {1 ... 1 0 ... 0}
    std::vector<bool> stencil(n);
    for(size_t i=0;i<K;++i)
        stencil[i]=true;

    //apply permutations to initial stencil
    do
    {
         //generate dynamic_bitset from permuted vector<bool>
         boost::dynamic_bitset<> temp(n);
         for(size_t i=0;i<n;++i)
              temp[i]=stencil[i];

         //count the occurence of the stencil
         size_t count=0;
         for(size_t j=0;j<currentSet.size();++j)
         {
              if((currentSet[j] & temp) == temp)
                 ++count;
         }

         //remove if at least one and less than thresh is found
         if(count<thresh && count>0)
         {
              boost::dynamic_bitset<> tempFlip=temp;
              tempFlip.flip();
              for(size_t j=0;j<currentSet.size();++j)
              {
                    //remove stencil from all bitset which contain it
                    if((currentSet[j] & temp) == temp)
                      currentSet[j]= (currentSet[j] & tempFlip);
              }
         }
    }
    while(std::prev_permutation(stencil.begin(),stencil.end()));

    //further remove all supersets which contain less than K elements
    for(size_t j=0;j<currentSet.size();++j)
         if(currentSet[j].count()<K)
         {
               currentSet[j]=boost::dynamic_bitset<>(n,0);
         }
}
```

The code can be used like this:

```
int main()
{
    //initialize set of three bit-vectors (all elements to true)
    std::vector<boost::dynamic_bitset<> > yourSet(3, boost::dynamic_bitset<>(5, (1<<5)-1) );

    //set corresponding elements to false
    yourSet[1][1]=false;
    yourSet[1][3]=false;
    yourSet[2][1]=false;
    yourSet[2][4]=false;

    std::cout<<"Original sets"<<std::endl;
    for(size_t i=0;i<3;++i)
        std::cout<<screenOutput(yourSet[i])<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::endl;

    removeSubsets(yourSet, 1, 2);
    std::cout<<"After iteration 1:"<<std::endl;
    for(size_t i=0;i<3;++i)
        std::cout<<screenOutput(yourSet[i])<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::endl;

    removeSubsets(yourSet, 2, 2);
    std::cout<<"After iteration 2:"<<std::endl;
    for(size_t i=0;i<3;++i)
        std::cout<<screenOutput(yourSet[i])<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::endl;

    removeSubsets(yourSet, 3, 2);
    std::cout<<"After iteration 3:"<<std::endl;
    for(size_t i=0;i<3;++i)
        std::cout<<screenOutput(yourSet[i])<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

It outputs:

```
Original set:
{1 2 3 4 5}
{1 3 5}
{1 3 4}

After iteration 1:
{1 3 4 5}
{1 3 5}
{1 3 4}

After iteration 2:
{}
{1 3 5}
{1 3 4}

After iteration 3:
{}
{}
{}
```

Man, I obviously have too much time.

---

**EDIT**: corrected code. Still you have to check whether it actually brings what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm beginner in programing, and I didn't use or even install boost libraries before, but I will now. the code you wrote is very helpful, it opens my mind for another perspective, I'm sure I will learn a lot here. I appreciate the time you spent to help me

Comment: You're welcome. I hope the algorithm (and the code) is correct as well -- if not, please state it here.